# Why is my game collision detection off by 500px?

Tags: java, 2d, collision-detection, collision, alien

I'm making something like r-type; I've made spaceship, missiles, aliens, and everything is working except collision detection. It seems to record collision between player and enemy in about 500 pixels before the actual alien comes and says that I lost.

Board.java:

```
public void checkCollisions() {
    Rectangle r1 = al.getBounds();
    ArrayList missiles = Craft.getMissiles();
    for (int w = 0; w < missiles.size(); w++)
    {
         Missile m = (Missile) missiles.get(w);
         Rectangle m1 = m.getRect();
         if (r1.intersects (m1) && al.Alive()) {
             al.isAlive = false;
             m.visible = false;
         }

    }

    Rectangle c = p.getBounds();
    if (c.intersects(r1)) {
        lost = true;
    }
```

Craft.java:

```
public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
}
```

Enemy.java:

```
public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
}
```

As I said - missiles are working perfectly, but collision detection between craft and alien detects in `x = 458`, while it should in about 1100 - 1200.

Comment: "Can you help me with it?" - No if you don't provide any useful information about your problem / collision detection algorithm / ..

Comment: Someone might be able to help if you gave some code to work with. Honestly how can you realistically expect any answers to this without seeing your code.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are creating the Rectangles objects with bad coordinates. Use `System.out.println(String s)` to print the coordinates the Rectangle is created with and check if they are correct.

I suspect the player's Rectangle has bad coordinates, because the missiles work fine, as you said.

Can you send me the full code of your game? I would like to try it...